# Consuming a nested JSON from a POST request, can't assign the nested JSON to my class

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebAPI project that recieves a JSON string, which should initiate a new object and fill its values. My classes look like this:

```
    public class User
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string libraryId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime joiningDate { get; set; }
    public string zone { get; set; }
    public List<Rental> rental { get; set; }
}

    public class Rental
{
    public Dictionary<DateTime, int> rental;
}
```

and  the JSON object I'm recieving is something like this:

```
{
    "email": "a@b.ca",
    "libraryId": "314159",
    "name": "Jon Doe",
    "joiningDate": "12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM",
    "zone": "13",
    "Rental": 
        [
            {"12/31/1999 11:59:59 PM": 12}, 
            {"12/30/2999 11:59:59 PM": 13}
        ]
}
```

Now, to validate that the object is correctly populated, I send the object back in the response

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]JObject incoming)
    {
        string toString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(incoming);                
        User request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(toString);     

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, request);
    }
```

The nested JSON comes always looking like this:

```
    "Rental": [
    {
        "Rental": null
    },
    {
        "Rental": null
    }
]
```

My question is: how should I build the Rental class so that I can properly populate it with the input from my JSON string? I tried to keep the Dictionary of rentals in the User class itself instead of its own class, but it returned an error.

Comment: Write a custom json converter. During deserialization, pass the custom converter. And let the custom converter handle the Rental by mapping the values to KeyValue pairs.

Comment: More info on Custom Json converter can be found here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Rental` class should look like:

```
public class Rental
{
    public KeyValuePair<DateTime, int> rental;
}
```

Since each entry in the array is a `KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>` and not a `Dictionary<DateTime, int>`.

A different approach would be to change the json's structure to:

```
{
    "email": "a@b.ca",
    "libraryId": "314159",
    "name": "Jon Doe",
    "joiningDate": "12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM",
    "zone": "13",
    "Rentals": 
     {
         "12/31/1999 11:59:59 PM": 12, 
         "12/30/2999 11:59:59 PM": 13
     }
}
```

And the class to:

```
public class User
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string libraryId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime joiningDate { get; set; }
    public string zone { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<DateTime, int> rentals {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: This returns multiple instances from rental in an array looking like this: "rental":[{ "rental":{"key": "...", "Value":"..."}}, {....}]. What I am trying to do is to have it identical as the input, with a `DateTime` as key, and an `int` as its value

Comment: I also gave you a different approach. Instead of working with an Array of KeyValuePairs, I think it's better to work with a dictionary(if it's possible).